# Dolphin Emulator Android port modifications

Tags: android, strings, local-variables, binary-editing

I am modifying the [Dolphin Emulator Alpha](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dolphinemu.dolphinemu&hl=en) for android, but I'm having some trouble with a string in it's `smali` code. The value I am having trouble with is `dolphin-emu`, it is the name of the folder that houses the emulators data and files. So far I have olny found two files containing the string, a configuration file in the `assets` folder, and a smali script. The issue is that even afyer changing both strings to `Dolphin Emulator`, the folder is still generated as `dolphin-emu`. I have scoured the application for **any** other references to this string and cannot find any more. How is the folder being generated with this name if I have replaced the string that represents it?

I am using [APK Editor Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gmail.heagoo.apkeditor.pro&hl=en) to modify the app, this is the method I almost always use. I've been modding android apps for years and have modded hundreds of them, but this one has me truly stumped. I've used every method I have developed over the years to hunt it down and nothing works. Using the built-in search function, I have searched for these strings to see if it is "split" or possibly even hidden:

```
"dolphin-emu"
"dolphin
"/dolphin
emu"
emu/"
"DOLPHIN-EMU"
ect...
```

Nothing else turns up, the app *is not* obfuscated or protected, and I can't find anything else that could potentialy hold the string I am trying to mod. Initially this was about simply changing the value, but now I just want to figure out how this is happening. Even uninstalling then re-installing after modifying the APK did not work, I thought that it may be possible for a settings file in the apps data folder to "remember" where the folder was stored. I've ***never*** had this much trouble locating and modifying a string in an app before.

Comment: isn't the project open source?

Comment: Yes, but even still, knowing what causes this is very perplexing to me and I would like to find out how to modify the string in the current build. I'll tinker with the source to see If I can trace the source there in the mean time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I did some more digging in the APK, I found what handles the fylesystem for the emulator. It is the `libmain.so` binary. Because it is handled by this file, modifying it is next to imposdible, this is because `.so` files are akin to windiws `.dll` binaries and are signed. Since modifying the file is not really an option, the only alternative answer to changing the emulators filesystem is to re-build it from the [source code](https://github.com/dolphin-emu/dolphin).

[image: The values were located using a hex editor.]

This is the first instance I have found something like this in an android app. Usually modifying file paths can be achieved through decompiling and modifying the `DEX`. Because of this, looking into the `.so` binaries was the *last* place I looked.